# Delete specific values in a matrix according to two position vectors

Tags: r, matrix

My aim is to delete specific positions in a matrix according to a vector. Just giving you a small example.

```
  Users_pos <- c(1,2)
  Items_pos <- c(3,2)
```

Given a Matrix A:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

My aim according to the two Vectors User_pos and Item_pos is to delete the following values

```
A[1,3] and A[3,2]
```

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to do so without typing in the values for rows and columns by hand.

Comment: Since you set `Users_pos <- c(1, 2)`, do you mean you want to remove `A[1,2]` instead of `A[1,3]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index `k` elements in a matrix `A` using `A[X]`, where `X` is a k-row, 2-column matrix where each row is the (row, col) value of the indicated element. Therefore, you can index your two elements in `A` with the following indexing matrix:

```
rbind(Users_pos, Items_pos)
#           [,1] [,2]
# Users_pos    1    2
# Items_pos    3    2
```

Using this indexing, you could choose to extract the information current stored with `A[X]` or replace those elements with `A[X] <- new.values`. If you, for instance, wanted to replace these elements with `NA`, you could do:

```
A[rbind(Users_pos, Items_pos)] <- NA
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   NA    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    7   NA    9
```

Comment: Just another question is it possible to fill these values which i switched to na by values which i produced by another function?

Comment: @HansDampf sure, it's `A[rbind(Users_pos, Items_pos)] <- new.values`.

Comment: Thank you very much :)  it was easier than i expected :)